# JSON seems to execute after all other code

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift

The following Swift code has to run twice in order to display the JSON data in a label. On the first run the label simply remains blank. It seems to me that the issue could be something along the lines of the JSON part of the code runs last, but I can't figure out why. I have included the code below. I'm still a rookie, so be gentle :D

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var labelDegrees: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var labelSpeed: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Set logo in nav bar

    navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "logo"))



    // Global save values

    var appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

    var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!



    // JSON Fetching

    let urlPath = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=55.564120&lon=12.568605"

    let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

        if (error != nil) {
            println(error)
        }
        else {


            // Delete old entries in CoreData

            var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "WindData")

            request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

            var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)

            for result in results! {

                context.deleteObject(result as NSManagedObject)
                context.save(nil)

            }

            // Start fetching JSON


            let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary


            var item = jsonResult["wind"] as NSDictionary

            var degrees:Float = item["deg"] as Float
            var speed:Float = item["speed"] as Float


            // Start saving JSON

            var newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("WindData", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

            var speedValue:Float = speed as Float
            var degreesValue:Float = degrees as Float

            newItem.setValue(speedValue, forKey: "speed")
            newItem.setValue(degreesValue, forKey: "degrees")

            context.save(nil)



        }

    })

    task.resume()

    // Start fetching from CoreData

    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "WindData")

    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)

    if results!.count > 0 {

        for result in results as [NSManagedObject] {


            let degrees:Float = result.valueForKey("degrees")! as Float
            let speed:Float = result.valueForKey("speed")! as Float

            if speed > 6.0 {

                self.labelDegrees.text = "Go kitesurf: \(speed) m/s"


            }
            else {

                self.labelDegrees.text = "Stay in: \(speed) m/s"


            }


        }
    }
    else {
        println("No data")
    }


}
```

Comment: Your code after "start fetching from core data" will run _before_ the `NSURLSession` completion handler closure does. This code should go into the closure, too. Also because that closure may not run on the main thread, don't forget to dispatch the UI updates back to the main thread with `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually fetching the data on another thread with  `dataTaskWithURL`.So you need to write      `// Start fetching from CoreData` code in `dataTaskWithURL`.As `dataTaskWithURL` will not immediately executed so   `// Start fetching from CoreData` code will get called first while `dataTaskWithURL` is fetching the data.So replece the code with below

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var labelDegrees: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var labelSpeed: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Set logo in nav bar

    navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "logo"))



    // Global save values

    var appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

    var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!



    // JSON Fetching

    let urlPath = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=55.564120&lon=12.568605"

    let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
  let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            if (error != nil) {
                println(error)
            }
            else {


                // Delete old entries in CoreData

                var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "WindData")

                request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

                var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)

                for result in results! {

                    context.deleteObject(result as NSManagedObject)
                    context.save(nil)

                }

                // Start fetching JSON


                let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary


                var item = jsonResult["wind"] as NSDictionary

                var degrees:Float = item["deg"] as Float
                var speed:Float = item["speed"] as Float


                // Start saving JSON

                var newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("WindData", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

                var speedValue:Float = speed as Float
                var degreesValue:Float = degrees as Float

                newItem.setValue(speedValue, forKey: "speed")
                newItem.setValue(degreesValue, forKey: "degrees")

                context.save(nil)



            }

            // Start fetching from CoreData

            var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "WindData")

            request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

            var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)

            if results!.count > 0 {

                for result in results as [NSManagedObject] {


                    let degrees:Float = result.valueForKey("degrees")! as Float
                    let speed:Float = result.valueForKey("speed")! as Float


                      if speed > 6.0 {
                         self.labelDegrees.text = "Go kitesurf: \(speed) m/s"
                     }
                     else {
                         self.labelDegrees.text = "Stay in: \(speed) m/s"
                     }

                                       }
            }
            else {
                println("No data")
            }
            });
        })

        task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Remember to dispatch UI updates (and probably CoreData stuff, too) to main thread.

Comment: @Rob until and unless managed context will not call by another thread nothing will happen.

Comment: @codester And that is what Rob meant: the completion block is not dispatched on the main thread.